# Calculating pressure of fluid through a pipe to get desired water flow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

You design a bathroom at the second floor in a house. You like to get in **3.0 s 1.0 L** of water out of the water faucet. The pipe to the faucet has an inner diameter of **0.80 cm**. It is connected to the fresh water system of the house which uses a pipes with an inner diameter of **2.2 cm**. In the basement at ground level, the fresh water system is connected to a water pump. What pressure does the pump have to establish so that you get the desired water flow in the bathroom, located **5.7 m** above ground level (neglect any other connections and branches in the water system).

**Attempt:**

I started trying to lay down the variables in the Bernoulli's equation:

$P_1+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2+\rho gh_1 = P_2+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2+\rho gh_2$

$\text{From the continuity equation: $A_1V_1=A_2V_2, V1=1.76\times 10^{-4}m/s$}$

$\rho = 1000kg/m^3,\:g=-9.8m/s^2,\:h_1=0m,\:h_2=5.7m,\:V_2=0.00033m/s$

$\text{I am wondering what is $P_1$ , is it 0? Are the variables above correct?}$

Comment: P1 must be higher than P2, as the driving force for fluid flow is a pressure difference.  And I'm just curious ... why do you need to get 1/3 L/s of flow rate?